# Type 'FirebaseOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Name not found issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to implement the push notification system in app. but whatever plugin I use it gives me a "Name not found" error. Later I found out that it not push notification issue. Its a typing issue I guess but could not find how to solve.
I am new to ionic develpoment. Please help.

I have tried some typing plugins but nothing worked.

Answer (score 6):

In app.module.ts fille add import wiht **/ngx**

import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';

Answer copy pasted from link -> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/firebase-is-not-assignable-as-provider-in-app-module-ts/154572